# Floating Menu with @Media

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a web application and am wanting to create a floating menu in which it stays fixed and floating at the top when arriving in width `min-width: 340px` and `max-width:640px`, I give a `display: block;` for the menu to appear,but the menu does not appear.

menu appears at the top of the page but does not appear

[image]

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 340px) and (max-width:640px) {
  #imagem_principal {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 210px;
  }
  .busca {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    position: relat??ive;
  }
  #campo_busca {
    width: 230px;
  }
  .menu_superior {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-fixed {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu_2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-fixed {
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: #6495ED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 20pt;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="header-fixed">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-left">
        <a class="fa fa-home"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <a class="fa fa-user"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have display:none in your .header-fiixed.css after you put display:block above it so it is cancelling it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `display:none;` in your css for `.header-fixed` this hides your header. Just remove it and it will appear.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 340px) and (max-width:640px) {
  #imagem_principal {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 210px;
  }
  .busca {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #campo_busca {
    width: 230px;
  }
  .menu_superior {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-fixed {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu_2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-fixed {
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #6495ED;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 20pt;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="header-fixed">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-left">
        <a class="fa fa-home"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
        <a class="fa fa-user"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-right">
        <a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```